# Android Inhibit Navigation Bar Back button

Tags: android

I have developed a game for the Android system. I have no use for the Back Navigation button in my application. However when the user selects the Back Navigation button in the middle of the game and then returns to the game, the application is restarted. How can I suppress the Back button action so that the back button becomes inoperative, or better still the Back button acts in the usual way but the application is not restarted after returning to it. The other two buttons or answering the phone etc. do not reset the application.

Answer (score 0):

Override the onKeyDown method in your Activity and have it return true if the back button is the key that was pressed (instead of calling super):

```
@Override
public void onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent keyEvent)
{
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK && event.getRepeatCount() == 0)
        return true;

    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, keyEvent);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution. Not to put too fine a point on it there were 2 problems with the code snippet. 1st line void should be Boolean and 3rd line event should be keyEvent.